# How to read application items integrated in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: .net, office-interop

I have a (document management system) application which is integrated in Microsoft outlook which provides the result as different mail items section in columns like title,version of document, author etc. The problem: I am able to read the normal mail items from the inbox folder but not the search results from this integrated application.

It seems I am not able to read the results because it is not part of the Outlook Interop object.

Could somebody help me with this to read the results?

Comment: It is unclear whether this is your own add-in into Outlook using Interop or whether this is an application you licensed from a vendor (Autonomy/iManage, now HP I believe, has an Outlook add-in for its DMS). If this is your own application, you need to post relevant code and if possible explain where are stuck. Alternately if this is an add-in that you purchased/licensed and you are not writing any code against it, then best bet would be to reach out to that vendor's support site. Please edit your question or it will likely be flagged for closure or removal

Comment: The application is Autonomy/imanage which I need to automate . So I need to read those results and then validate the search results on the basis of search criteria.

Comment: I can try to help but you need to post relevant code so I can get into the context, even if it involves their API (which I have access to). Search results should be accessible through Interop: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.results(v=office.12).aspx